# Microsoft Graph adding Directory.Read.All permission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, microsoft-graph-api

We are creating a service that requires permission to view other users' (inside the organization) emails. I'm under the impression that two required permissions are Mail.Read and Directory.Read.All. Since I'm not an admin, I got our admin to try it and he still gets 'Access denied'. Is it possible for the admin to give me the necessary directory permissions?

Am I missing something?

(Sorry if I am ambiguous, I am brand new to Graph. Please ask me any question that will help clarify)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enabled the Mail.Read *application permission* (Read mail in all mailboxes). There is also a Mail.Read *delegated permission* (Read user mail), which gives you access only to the signed-in user's mailbox.

An admin must grant that permission in Azure Portal for the application. From that point on, the application by itself (with no signed-in user) should be able to access any user's email in the organization.